# Can We Make C# WinForms Application using MongoDB Database Without MongoDB Installed on Device?

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms

Can we make it ? I meant an application for client. Client don't need to install mongodb in his/her pc. Just install our application that build with using MongoDB as the database. So the client application have process to database to server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your application should connect to server DB so I don't see why it should need anything additional on client side.